# Adding a row if it does not exist in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Inside a table there are 2 columns: `userid` and `roleid`. Every user should atleast have `roleid` 4 . There are currently around 10.000 records, but somehow a small amount of users do not have this role.

Visual example:

```
userid  |  roleid
1          1
1          4
2          1
2          4
3          1 <---------- userid 3 misses roleid 4!
4          1
4          4
```

Is it possible to execute a query and add a row with the userid and roleid when that combination does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
insert into userRoles(userid, roleid)
    select userid, 4
    from userRoles
    group by userid
    having sum(roleid = 4) = 0;
```

The `sum(role = 4)` in the `having` clause counts the number of rows for each user that have `4`.  The `= 0` says there are none.

Note:  This gives all users in this table a role id of 4.  There may be users with no roles at all.

If you want them, then use the `users` table:

```
insert into userRoles(userid, roleid)
    select u.userid, 4
    from users u
    where not exists (select 1 from userRoles ur where ur.userid = u.userid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should search for  user that have not 4 in roleID

```
insert into yourTable ( userId, roledid)
select userid, 4
from yourTable 
where roleid <>4
```